# Removing specific path segments from url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My current url structure looks like this:

```
Served from /var/www/app:

    /example.com/app/news
    /example.com/app/files
    /example.com/app/offers

Served from /var/www:

    /example.com/admin
```

Slightly strange structure as I've bolted the 'app' onto a current CMS simply by creating a new `app` sub-directory in the root folder. What I want to do is to serve the app files from eg:

```
/example.com/news
/example.com/files
/example.com/offers
```

i.e. just removing `app` from the url. But I obviously still want the `/admin/` routes to be served from the original root directory. How can I go about this?

Comment: Something you tried on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin$
RewriteRule (.*) /app/$1 [L]
```

You will find the documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html